# How is the time complexity of 2 nested while loops is o(N) in my function fixing?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, time-complexity

input = [10, 9, 7, 18, 13, 19, 4, 20, 21, 14]
Output : 10 9 18 7 20 19 4 13 14 21

```
def fixing(arr):
    oddIdx = 1
    evenIdx = 0
    while True:
        while evenIdx < len(arr) and arr[evenIdx] %2 ==0:
            evenIdx +=2
        while oddIdx < len(arr) and arr[oddIdx] % 2!=0:
            oddIdx+=2
        if evenIdx < len(arr) and oddIdx < len(arr):
            arr[evenIdx], arr[oddIdx] = arr[oddIdx], arr[evenIdx]
        else:
            break
    return arr
```

Is it because we are not ignoring the outer loop? If yes, why and if not, why not? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets break it down.

The condition for the `while True` depends on `evenIdx < len(arr) and oddIdx < len(arr)`.

So the outer loop will not iterate more than O(N) where `N=len(arr)`.

But what about the inner loops?

Lets consider the options here:

1. We only have 1 outer loop iteration where inner functions advance `evenIdx` and `oddIdx` to the point where we break. So overall O(N).
2. The outer loop iterate K times. But `evenIdx` and `oddIdx` **do not reset**. In iteration 1, `evenIdx/oddIdx` get to somewhere between 0 to N, iteration 2 **they still continue to advance**, same for iteration 3 up to iteration K. Eventually `evenIdx/oddIdx` advanced O(N) times. So again O(N).

There is a more strict analysis that can be done but it is still O(N).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't reset `evenIdx` or `oddIdx` back to `0` each time through the outer loop. Each time the outer loop repeats, the inner loops start from where they left off the previous time.

So you don't perform multiple iterations over the list -- you break out of the outer loop as soon as both inner loops reach the end. And each inner loop only visits the even or odd elements once.

Comment: How do you know that the inner loops reach the end?

Comment: If the inner loops haven't reached the end, the `if` statement swaps the even and odd elements. That means that the even/odd tests that failed on the previous iteration will succeed, so it will increment the indexes again. Eventually this process will reach the end.